# Dynamically assign event in javascript object

Tags: javascript, events, dynamic

I have following javascript class:

```
var ImageGallery = function(arr) {
    var ImgArr = arr;
    var MainImgId = "";

    this.build = function() {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        for (var i = 0; i < ImgArr.length; i++) {
            var img = document.createElement("img");
            img.scr = ImgArr[i];
            // what to do next, how to assign loadMainImage function ?????
            img.onclick = 
            div.appendChild(img); 

        }
    }

    this.loadMainImage = function(imgPath) {
        document.getElementById(MainImgId).src = imgPath;
    }
}
```

next, in code I create an object of that class:

```
var gallery = new ImageGallery(someArrWithPaths);
gallery.MainImgId = 'idOfMainImg';
gallery.build();
```

How can I assign img.onclick event to launch loadMainImage(imgPath) function every time I click on the image?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your declaration of `loadMainImage` is invalid. You probably want `this.loadMainImage = function(imgPath) { ... }`.

Comment: What would the `imgPath` parameter be when the image is clicked?

Comment: loadMainImage function fixed for Brian Donovan

Comment: i think [clicked image element].src - for casablanca

Comment: Not really related to your question, but JavaScript standards suggest beginning your variable names with lowercase letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to capture the current value of `this` (which refers to the `ImageGallery` object) and invoke `loadMainImage` on it within `onclick`. Inside `onclick`, `this` refers to the image itself, so `this.src` will give you the image source:

```
var self = this;
img.onclick = function() {
  self.loadMainImage(this.src);
};
```

Comment: this code can possibly leak... JavaScript function points to img as DOM element, which points to JavaScript "self" variable in its onclick handler... Can't tell for sure, just looks like circular reference and worth to test for leaks

Answer (score 0):

I would try to avoid using methods like onevent (in your case onclick), because it is easy to loose this handler (just writing img.onclick somewhere else will override previous handler)

try to use some javascript library (like jQuery), it will simplify your development at least a bit. And back to your question, using [YUI 2](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/) I would write so:

```
var imgCount = ImgArr.length; // do not use ImgArr.length in for definition, it is better 
// to save it once and then use... otherwise each time in loop will look up ImgArr object to find length property
for (var i = 0; i < imgCount; i++) {
     var img = document.createElement("img");
     var src = ImgArr[i];
     img.scr = src ;
     YAHOO.util.Event.addListener(img, "click", this.loadMainImage, src, this);
}
```

You can find similar function in jQuery or other frameworks. What it does:
`YAHOO.util.Event.addListener(obj, event, handler, argument, context)` - attach event listener to `obj`, for `event` and `handler` specified. `argument` - what to pass to that handler, and `context` to execute that handler (in your case it will be just `this`)

Doing this just don't forget to unattach this handler when you unload your page (or whatever you do), e.g.  `YAHOO.util.Event.removeListener(img, "click", this.loadMainImage)`, or calling function which removes all listener attached (like YUI's `purgeElement`). Yes, things are a bit easier when you use `img.onclick = ...;`, seems like in this case browser will take care about it.